# C# MVC overwriting required annotation error message doesn't work

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api

I have a user class with annotations for required fields.

```
public class User
{
    [DataMember(Name = "firstName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="FIST_NAME_REQUIRED")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "lastName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "LAST_NAME_REQUIRED")]
    [Custom(ErrorMessage = "CUSTOM_MESSAGE")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This class is the argument of a POST API call.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Create(User request)
{
    var response = new ApiResponse();
    if (request != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        [Code here]
    }
    else
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Message = ModelState.Values.Count() > 0 ModelState.Values.Select(value => value.Errors).Select(error =>     error.First().ErrorMessage).Aggregate((result, next) => result + ", " + next) :     string.Empty ;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
    }
}
```

My problem is when I call the API controller action with no first name for example, I get the default error message "The FirsName property is required." instead of my custom error message "FIRST_NAME_REQUIRED".

The error message for the Custom validator works fine though.

Couldn't find any clue about it on Google so it might be something very specific to my code but I can't think of anything.

Any idea ?

Comment: FYI, WebApi is a part of the MVC4 distribution, but is not in and of itself part of asp.net mvc.  It's a separate package, and can be installed separately from MVC.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to WebApi or not. Do you think so?

Comment: You said "API Controller"

Comment: So for information, custom error message don't work with ModelState validation but works with the following the method Validator.TryValidateObject Method (Object, ValidationContext, ICollection<ValidationResult>, Boolean)

Comment: @MystereMan Yes I'm using WebApi but I don't know if the issue has to do with it or not.

Comment: Hm. Just gave it a quick test on an empty project. Worked fine and I get the custom error message.

Comment: Also, you misspelled FIRST in your custom error message.

Comment: You're using DataMember attribute, so I take it you have changed your serialization?

Comment: What do you mean "changed your serialization" @SimonC? My controller derives from ApiController so it's using WebApi serialization.